# Firebase Analytics App and Big Query Count User

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

How user are counted in firebase analytics?
I launched the query below, but I have an higher number in GA dashboard (9k user and 3.5k new user) instead of BigQuery (7.190)

```
SELECT count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as user
FROM `pn.analytics_nid.events_*` 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210302' AND '20210308'
```

and how to calculate in Big Query new users?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to calculate the number of users on firebase console.

You can count new users like bellow,

```
SELECT count(distinct user_pseudo_id) as user
FROM `pn.analytics_nid.events_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20210302' AND '20210308'
AND event_name = 'first_open'
```

btw, precisely it depends on your definition of "new user". So take a look this link for `first_open` meaning.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9234069?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, but I've already try using event_name = first_open, but in this case big query return 5K (new user?), GA 3.5K. So I think both queries to count users and new users are wrong. I would like to know how user and new user are counted